# JQuery Tabs UI - Menu rotation - OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut

Tags: javascript, tabs, mouseevent, rotation, jquery-ui-tabs

I am currently working with a tab menu which cycles through automatically.
Once I mouseover one of the tabs the "rotation" should stop on the selected tab and when I mouseout it should continue rotating from the selected tab item.

```
$("#featured > ul").tabs({ 
                     event: 'mouseover', 
                     fx: { opacity: "toggle"} })
                   .tabs("rotate", 10000, true);
```

At the moment the onmouseover selects the correct tab but it keeps rotating.

I have been stuck on this for AGES so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Hi Karim,

Almost there.
$("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: "toggle"} }).tabs("rotate", 1000, true);

$("#featured > ul").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).tabs("rotate", 0);
}).mouseout(function() {
 $(this).tabs("rotate", 1000, true);
});

Although the cycle stops and starts fine, how would you recommend to start the cycle from a button selected which was not within the general loop..
Eg.. 1,2,3
if we are on 3 within the cycle and I mouse over 1 then I would like 1 to be selected. when I mouse out the count should continue from 1.

Any Ideas?

Comment: $("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: "toggle"} }).tabs("rotate", 1000, true);

$("#featured > ul").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).tabs("rotate", 0);
}).mouseout(function() {
 $(this).tabs("rotate", 1000, true);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop rotation by setting the first argument to `0` or `null`:

```
.tabs("rotate", 0);
```

So I would imagine that you can simply do that on `mouseover`, and reset back to your defaults on `mouseout`:

```
$("#featured > ul").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).tabs("rotate", 0);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).tabs("rotate", 10000, true);
});
```

Comment: Almost there, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333511/javascript-scroll-menu-mouseover-selection-not-working-correctly-on-first-conta for my most current issue on this..